# How to remove callback option UI of CallKit after ending the call

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

In my app i'm using CallKit for incoming call. There is no outgoing call feature in the app. Everything is fine but when the receiver or dailer ends the call it shows the CallKit UI with call back option. I don't want to show callback option, how can I do it?

My code for ending the call

```swift
func end(call: SpeakerboxCall) {

    let endCallAction = CXEndCallAction(call: call.uuid)
    let transaction = CXTransaction()
    transaction.addAction(endCallAction)

    requestTransaction(transaction, action: "endCall")

}

private func requestTransaction(_ transaction: CXTransaction, action:
    String = "") {

    callController.request(transaction) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error requesting transaction: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Requested transaction \(action) successfully")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the callback option shows, then the call didn't end properly. So check the end call function properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have solved it. I was force quitting the CallKit where the transaction is not correctly completing.

```
 AppDelegate.shared.providerDelegate?.provider.reportCall(with: call.uuid, endedAt: nil, reason: CXCallEndedReason.remoteEnded)
```

We need to set endedAt to nil and reason to remoteEnded

Comment: It works to me! Thank you so much. shared instance can be access by using this command: "UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate"

Answer (score 2):

Close All Call (Swift4)

```
func performEndCallAction() {

    for call in self.cxCallController.callObserver.calls {

        let endCallAction = CXEndCallAction(call: call.uuid)
        let transaction = CXTransaction(action: endCallAction)

        cxCallController.request(transaction) { error in
            if let error = error {
                NSLog("EndCallAction transaction request failed: \(error.localizedDescription).")
                return
            }

            NSLog("EndCallAction transaction request successful")

        }

    }

}
```